# Room database query not working in android

Tags: android, android-room

In my query i need to find out particular column data form database like count and sum. the given query as follow

```
select t_type, count(t_type),sum(amount) from <TableName> where ispresent = 'false' and code='00' group by t_type;
```

Comment: post your code?

Comment: If you could please post your code.

Comment: i don't post my code. can you help me on that query only. i just need <Selected type their count and sum of their amount> using room database in android studio.

Comment: You could just try these 3 things in 3 different queries and log their results. **Count returns in INT** while **sum will return your sum in whatever datatype you have assigned** and **for the row, you can use string livedata list** and see for every function what data is being returned and then combine your query. @RohitB.

Comment: Possible in a one query like SQL in room database. @Kartik

Comment: what I am suggesting is try 3 different queries once and see if u get desirable results and then you may come to know where you are wrong. Maybe it can be the return type of your function also. @RohitB.

Comment: @Kartik your suggestion is working properly thank you :)

Comment: Glad to know that worked well for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query seems fine. You can check out your query by running it on your Room database by directly running it on the database using [Stetho](https://facebook.github.io/stetho/) debugging tool by facebook.

You can directly run this query in Chrome Dev tool using Stetho and check out what is the problem.

Hope it helps!